# Using PHP Built-in Server on 127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: php, localhost

Windows 10, chrome 79.

Could someone please explain why I can access a page with `php`'s built in server using `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080` but not `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000`, which gives `This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.`

It also seems to work with `127.0.0.1:80` and `localhost:80`.

I've tried commenting and uncommenting `127.0.0.1         localhost` in hosts.

Comment: What enviroment are you running? linux/windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Comment: In PowerShell:   

Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 8000).OwningProcess

Comment: Nothing on port 8000. Yet it works with port 80, not 8000.